# java arrays wont go along

Tags: java

how can i sort the itemArray along with its price? because i have a problem that if i sort the items it will be sorted alphabetically but the price wont go along with the item.

```
public class finalsProj{

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int itemsInv=0;
    static int price=0;
    static char NO = 'N';
    static String[] itemArray;
    static String[] priceArray;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        do{
            System.out.print("Input the number of items: ");
            itemsInv = in.nextInt();

            if(itemsInv>0){
                System.out.print("Input N to change the number Y to Continue : ");
                NO = in.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            }
        }while(NO == 'N' || NO == 'n');

        if(NO == 'Y'){
            itemArray = new String[itemsInv];
            priceArray = new String[itemsInv];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter the name of item " + (i+1) + " : ");
            itemArray[i] = in2.nextLine();
            do{
                System.out.print("Price: ");
                priceArray[i] = in3.nextLine();

                if(priceArray[i] < 0){
                    System.out.println("Input must be a VALID number");
                }
            }while(priceArray[i] < 0);
        }

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Items Available: " + "\nItem Name\tItem Price");

        for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(itemArray[i] + "\t\t" + 'P' + priceArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

the output is my problem on this 1

Comment: why does your title say _#java script_ ?

Comment: Don't try to store data across multiple data structures like that.  Instead, write a class that encapsulates all the data you care about, and make a list of *that*.